# how to set umask permissions mask to 777?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm interested in creating a shell script that is capable of creating various operations (creating files,users, groups and more), and for that it's necessary to change the permissions mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the `umask 777` type the following command at shell prompt:

```
umask 777
mkdir dir1
touch file
ls -ld dir1 file
```

Hope this helps.